# Adding a marker on a Mapbox map in flutter (Mapbox GL)

Tags: android, flutter, dictionary, mapbox, symbols

I've just started designing an app that uses the Flutter Mapbox GL library and would like to add a marker on the map corresponding to assigned lat long.

Could someone explain to where to add, and how to use the MapboxMapController Class in my code? I'm very new to programming, let alone flutter. Or is there a different way which I'm missing?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mapbox_gl/mapbox_gl.dart';

class MapBoxWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapBoxWidgetState createState() => _MapBoxWidgetState();
}

class _MapBoxWidgetState extends State<MapBoxWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: MapboxMap(
          zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
          myLocationTrackingMode: MyLocationTrackingMode.TrackingGPS,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            zoom: 15,
            target: LatLng(53.5074, 0.1278),
          ),
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          accessToken:
              'pk.eyJ1IjoiZG.....',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you must use the MapboxMap onCreated parameter and use a function inside it to save your controller in a variable you would use later.
Example:

```
late MapboxController mapController;

...

MapboxMap(
          accessToken: MAPBOX_KEY,
          onMapCreated:(MapboxController controller){
             setState((){
                 mapController = controller;
             });
                        
          },
          initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(0.0, 0.0), zoom: 14),
        );

...
```

Then you can use it to animate the camera, and that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Before starting you first have to initialize the mapboxController like this

```
MapboxMapController? controller;

void _onMapCreated(MapboxMapController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
}
MapboxMap(
 accessToken: MapsDemo.ACCESS_TOKEN,
 //remember to add this line to initialize the controller when mapbox loaded successfully
 onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
 initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
   target: LatLng(-33.852, 151.211),
     zoom: 11.0,
   ),
 ),
```

**This way you can initialize the controller and now its your choice when you want to add the marker and in which way you want to add... Lets take this in a simple way adding marker**

**In this example I am getting an image from internet and showing as a marker on the map**

```
// in above Mapbox declaration when you initialize controller you can add marker there as well with following method

MapboxMap(
 accessToken: MapsDemo.ACCESS_TOKEN,
 onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
 // this method will call when your mapbox loaded successfully. You can add marker with your own need using button or anything
 onStyleLoadedCallback: _onStyleLoaded,
 initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
   target: LatLng(-33.852, 151.211),
     zoom: 11.0,
   ),
 ),


//now in styleLoaded method we fetch the image from link and show that in map

  void _onStyleLoaded() {
    addImageFromAsset("assetImage", "assets/symbols/custom-icon.png");
    addImageFromUrl(
        "networkImage", Uri.parse("https://via.placeholder.com/50"));
  }

  /// Adds an asset image to the currently displayed style
  Future<void> addImageFromAsset(String name, String assetName) async {
    final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load(assetName);
    final Uint8List list = bytes.buffer.asUint8List();
    return controller!.addImage(name, list);
  }

/// Adds a network image to the currently displayed style
  Future<void> addImageFromUrl(String name, Uri uri) async {
    var response = await http.get(uri);
    return controller!.addImage(name, response.bodyBytes);
  }

// even we add that image it won't show anything on the map it just type of saving image and when we want to show image as a marker on map simply call addSymbol method to add Image a s symbol on mapbox as marker


controller!.addSymbol(_getSymbolOptions(iconImage, availableNumbers.first))


where _getSymbolOptions is where you set various properties including latlng

SymbolOptions _getSymbolOptions(String iconImage, int symbolCount) {
    LatLng geometry = LatLng(
      center.latitude,
      center.longitude
    );
    return SymbolOptions(
            geometry: geometry,
            iconImage: iconImage,
    );
  }

Final Note: iconImage in symbolOptions and name from .addImage should be same to show the symbol
```

**For more practice you can navigate to the very detailed example repository by Mapbox itself [here](https://github.com/flutter-mapbox-gl/maps/tree/master/example)**